# Parse Array without key in nativescript-angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

**JsonStructure:**

```
{
    "share": [ 
            {      
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Denver",

            "address": [
                "people"
            ],

            "iconUrl": ""            
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Cook",
            "address": [
                "people",
                "student"
            ],
            "iconUrl": ""
        }
       ]
      }
```

I want to parse **address array** in Nativescript-angular2. IF you see address array, inside that there is no object. So i dont know how to parse it.

**Code:**

The code which i tried below:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < response.share.length; i++) {
     let myApp = new Share();
        myApp.address = share[i].address;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try parsing your JSON like this

```
for(s of response['share']){
   let add = s['address']; // address array of share obj
   add.forEach(address=>{console.log(address)}) // all addresses
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use flat() method**

> The flat() method creates a new array with all sub-array elements
>   concatenated into it recursively up to the specified depth.

```
 let d=  this.data.share.map((d)=>d.address);
 console.log(d.flat());
```

Or

**Use flatMap()**

> The flatMap() method first maps each element using a mapping function,
>   then flattens the result into a new array. It is identical to a map
>   followed by a flat of depth 1, but flatMap is often quite useful, as
>   merging both into one method is slightly more efficient.

```
this.data.share.flatMap((d)=>d.address)
```

RefforFlat:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

RefForFlatMaphttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/arrayfalt